# Hadoop's Configured equivalent in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, configuration

Hadoop provides `Configured` and `Configurable` to let classes access `Configuration` object. Is there any similar way in Spark other than passing `SparkConf` via constructor?

Answer (score 0):

- First,use conf/spark-defaults.conf to provide config,for example:

```
    spark.master            spark://5.6.7.8:7077
    spark.executor.memory   4g
    spark.eventLog.enabled  true
    spark.serializer        org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
```

- Second,use spark-submit to pass config arguments such as:

```
    ./bin/spark-submit --name "My app" --master local[4] --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=false
  --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps" myApp.jar
```